# Using multithreading to get continuous beep sound

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, beep

I'm trying to create a program in C++ where I play a beep sound, with a frequency and duration of the user's choice.

The program needs to continue running while playing the beep sound.

I figured out I should use multi-threading for this, but I don't have any experience with this.

For example, this is a simple program, but I get an error when I use `_beginthread`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

int freq = 0;
int sec = 0;
int mil = 0;

void beepTone(int freqq, int mill)
{
    Beep(freqq, mill);
    _endthread();
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Frequency?" << endl;
    cin >> freq;
    cout << "Duration?" << endl;
    cin >> sec;
    mil = 1000 * sec;
    _beginthread(beepTone(freq, mil), 0, NULL);
    cout << "Test Threading";
    return 0;
}
```

> Argument of type "void(*)(int freqq, int mill)" is incompatible with parameter of type "_beginthread_proc_type"

I think the point of this testing program is pretty clear.

I have code that runs, but in this code I can't choose my own frequency and duration:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

void beepTone(void *arg)
{
    Beep(1000, 3000);
    _endthread();
}

int main()
{
    _beginthread(beepTone, 0, NULL);
    cout << "Test Threading";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This one plays 1000Hz for 3 sec while continuing the program.

Can anyone help me on how can I tell the thread which frequency and duration to play?

Comment: can you use c++11; or must it be c++98?

Comment: It don't have to be c++98 specific, but to be honest I have no idea what the difference is between those two you said, and how to change between them.. 
If it can help you, I'm working with visual studio 2017 and i start my programs by just creating a new c++ project. So everything is in standard settings I guess.

Comment: vs2017 supports C++11, so you can use standard facility `<thread>` instead of function like `_beginthread`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick respons, but i'm not totally getting how i should implement the <thread> in my code. 
Like I said, I'm totally new to threading..

Comment: `_beginthread` is a C function. It expects a specific signature for the thread function pointer. You violate that contract. C++11 introduced threading into C++. C++ threads allow you to pass *any* function as a thread function. Visual Studio 2017 supports C++17, so you can take advantage of the C++ [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example fails to compile because you are actually calling `beepTone()` and then trying to pass its `void` return value to the `start_address` parameter of `_beginthread()`, which will not work.  You need to pass `beepTone()` itself to that parameter, not its return value.

Your second example is correctly passing `beepTone()` itself to `_beginThread()`, but is not passing any data to `beepTone()`.

Now, to accomplish what you want, `_beginthread()` has an `arglist` parameter that you can use to pass user data to your thread function.  That is what you need to use to send your beep values to the thread so it can then pass them to `Beep()`.

Try something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct beepParams
{
    int freq;
    int mil;
};

void __cdecl beepTone(void *arg)
{
    beepParams *params = static_cast<beepParams*>(arg);
    Beep(params->freq, params->mil);
    delete params;
    _endthread();
}

int main()
{
    int freq = 0, sec = 0, mil = 0;

    cout << "Frequency?" << endl;
    cin >> freq;
    cout << "Duration?" << endl;
    cin >> sec;
    mil = 1000 * sec;

    beepParams *params = new beepParams;
    params->freq = freq;
    params->mil = mil;

    if (_beginthread(&beepTone, 0, params) == -1)
        delete params;

    cout << "Test Threading";
    //...
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

That being said, if you are using C++11 or later, consider using `std::thread` instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct beepParams
{
    int freq;
    int mil;
};

void beepTone(beepParams params)
{
    Beep(params.freq, params.mil);
}

int main()
{
    int freq = 0, sec = 0, mil = 0;

    cout << "Frequency?" << endl;
    cin >> freq;
    cout << "Duration?" << endl;
    cin >> sec;
    mil = 1000 * sec;

    beepParams params;
    params.freq = freq;
    params.mil = mil;

    thread t(beepTone, params);
    t.detach();

    cout << "Test Threading";
    //...
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well. Son of a gun. I finally get a chance to sit down and answer this one and you beat me by about 20 seconds.

Comment: The first example is missing a calling convention on the thread procedure definition.

Comment: @IInspectable the calling convention of the thread procedure in `_beginthread()` is `__cdecl`. Most C/C++ compilers default to `__cdecl` when a calling convention is not explicitly stated. Obviously, if you configure the compiler's default to be something other than `__cdecl` then you need to state the calling convention explicitly so it matches the expected definition.